# CakePHP Query builder is not giving new column an alias

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

Ive inherited a project built in Cake PHP. On my local machine Ive added a new column in an existing table. When I move the code to the staging server, the page fails to load with an SQL error "column not found". Ive cleared the cache and made sure the new column exists. The interesting part is in the middle of the query, its asking for the field but is not prefixing it with the proper alias. Here is an example

```
  SELECT `User`.`id`, 
...

`PerformerDetail`.`address`, `billboard_image`, `PerformerDetail`.`photo1`,
```

The query builder is skipping the prefix, billboard_image should be prefixed with PerformerDetail

any idea??

Comment: Check beforeFind method and the model. Maybe it has some additional processing...

Answer (score 0):

There was a white space in the column name on the staging server  >.<